# Complicated Recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a function **nested_sum(L)** that will sum all the ints inside a list no matter if they are inside another list. This with calling recrusively to another function **mult2(n)**.

Example:

```
>>> nestedSum(mult2( [1,['a',3,'b',2],[4,['h',8,[10]]], -5]))
24
```

I tried to code this:

```
def mult2(n):
    if type(n) == int and n%2 ==0:
        return n

def nested_sum(L):
    total = 0 
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list):  
            total += nested_sum(i)
        else:
            total += i
    return total
```

**And unfortanetly I can't change the code of mult2(n) function. I can only change the nested_sum(L) function.**

Can someone please give me a clue what to do?
Thank you.

Comment: Must you use the mult2 function?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Ni. yes, I have to use that.

Comment: @Daenyth I can't code it correctly unfortanately

Comment: You still aren't saying what the problem is. What is the actual problem. What is the error? What behavior do you want to see and what do you actually see?

Comment: @Daenyth I'm trying to code the function nested_sum(L) that it will cal recrusively to the unchangeable function mult2(n). 
it will sum all the ints inside a list no matter if they are inside another list.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to achieve, what kind of use of mult2 you must implement, and why

Comment: this can be of interest: [flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that the example invocation correct:

```
nestedSum(mult2( [1,['a',3,'b',2],[4,['h',8,[10]]], -5]))
```

Calling `mult2()` on a list will always return `None`. Passing `None` to `nestedSum()` will always cause a `TypeError`.

`mult2()` is designed to filter out non-integers and odd integers. I think that you are supposed to pass `mult2` as a filter function to `nestedSum()`:

```
def mult2(n):
    if type(n) == int and n%2 ==0:
        return n

def nested_sum(L, predicate):
    total = 0
    for item in L:
        if isinstance(item, list):  
            total += nested_sum(item, predicate)
        elif predicate(item):
            total += item
    return total
```

Now to invoke the function, pass `mult2()` as the predicate function to nested_sum():

```
>>> nested_sum([1,['a',3,'b',2],[4,['h',8,[10]]], -5], mult2)
24
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Can you just tell me what is the meaning of "if L"? why did you use that?

Comment: @Netta: `if L:`? Was supposed to guard against `None` being passed in ( as done in the original invocation), but it can be removed. I've updated the answer to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to separate out the recursion into a function that only does that like in the following:

```
sum(x for x in iflatten(L) if cond)
```

where `iflatten` is an iterator returning version of the flatten function and `cond` is in your case `type(x) == int and x % 2 == 0`.

```
def iflatten(L):
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list):  
            for r in iflatten(i):
                yield r
        else:
            yield i
```

The code tests out like this:

```
L = [1,['a',3,'b',2],[4,['h',8,[10]]], -5]

def iflatten(L):
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list):  
            for r in iflatten(i):
                yield r
        else:
            yield i

sum(x for x in iflatten(L) if type(x) == int and x % 2 == 0)
```

results in `24`.

As you can't change

```
def mult2(n):
    if type(n) == int and n%2 ==0:
        return n
```

We can change the condition from `type(x) == int and x % 2 == 0` to `mult2(x) is not None` as all functions have an implicit `return None` at their end.

Lets test that too:

```
L = [1,['a',3,'b',2],[4,['h',8,[10]]], -5]

def iflatten(L):
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list):  
            for r in iflatten(i):
                yield r
        else:
            yield i

def mult2(n):
    if type(n) == int and n%2 ==0:
        return n

sum(x for x in iflatten(L) if mult2(x) is not None)
```

Also results in `24`

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it without using `mult2` but still must use recursion, this would do the job:

```
def sumArr(arr):
    return sum([numVal(item) for item in arr])

def numVal(item):
    if instanceof(item, int): return item
    elif instance(item, list): return sumArr(item)
    else: return 0

sumArr([1,['a',3,'b',2],[4,['h',8,[10]]], -5]) # >>> 23
```